# MVC 3 Date formatting - Dates only show in american

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, date

This seems a really stupid problem to have but it appears to be a problem none the less! I can't seem to get my dates to show in british format of dd/mm/yyyy they will only show in american format mm/dd/yyyy. I have added the following data attribute to my model:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

Can anyone shed any light on this? Its got to be something simple but its driving me nuts!

Cheers.

** EDIT **

Here is a snippet of the code from the View

```
<tr>
  <th>Start Date</th>
  <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.DateFrom, new { class = "datepicker" })</td>
  <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.DateFrom)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>End Date</th>
  <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.DateTo, new { class = "datepicker" })</td>
  <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.DateTo)</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify the culture in web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <globalization uiCulture="en-GB" culture="en-GB" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: Just tried that and the dates are unaffected, still showing mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: Have you taken your DisplayFormat attributes off, to avoid any conflict? It's certainly a common enough problem that's been solved this way before.

Comment: No joy Steve, removed the DisplayFormat and its still showing american!

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your View? you need to format the display of the date,

```
 @String.Format("{0:ddd, dd MMM yyyy}", item.StorageDate)
```

or try use an EditorTemplate for DateTime :)